# Pandas: resample with an external Series

Tags: python, pandas

I want to `resample` a `DataFrame` containing intraday data on market volume and market prices using an external `Series` with a `datetime` in it.

A sample of my `DataFrame` called `df` would look something like this:

(EDIT: corrected a mistake in the sample dataset)

```
Datetime               Volume    Price 
2013-04-15 21:45:00     100      50.00
2013-04-15 21:47:00     25       50.03
2013-04-15 21:52:00     15       50.05
2013-04-15 22:03:00     4        50.07
2013-04-15 22:04:00     145      50.38
2013-04-15 22:07:00     68       50.04
2013-04-15 22:12:00     157      49.93
2013-04-15 22:13:00     27       50.02
2013-04-15 22:19:00     37       49.91
```

The `Series` is called `beginpoints` (it are the beginpoints of each interval) and looks like:

```
0      2013-04-15 21:45:00
1      2013-04-15 22:04:00
2      2013-04-15 22:13:00
```

Given that I'm interested in the sum of the volume and the opening price of the interval I ultimately want to have the following solution:

```
Datetime                Volume     Price 
2013-04-15 21:45:00     144        50.00
2013-04-15 22:04:00     370        50.38
2013-04-15 22:13:00     64         50.02
```

I know that standard resampling goes something like `df.resample(‘5min’, how={‘Volume’:sum, ‘Price’:first})` for e.g.  5 minute intervals. However, when I try to modify this to my specific scenario and hence use `df.resample(beginpoints, how={‘Volume’:sum, ‘Price’:first})` I get a `ValueError`. This seems quite straightforward but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Anybody got an idea how to tackle this problem? Thanks!

Comment: There are duplicated datetime in `df`, like 22:08:00. Are they valid?

Comment: You're completely right, I made a silly mistake in making up some date by being too fast. This is corrected now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide an approach. First of all, I reset the index of `beginpoints` series and make `beginpoints` as the index.

Then the `index` column is extracted as a series to map `Datetime` column in `df`. There are `Datetime` values which are not a part of `beginpoints`, making corresponding `point` N/A. But since `Datetime` is sorted, we can use `ffill` to fill these N/A.

```
s = pd.Series(["2013-04-15 21:45:00", "2013-04-15 22:04:00","2013-04-15 22:13:00"], name="beginpoints")

t = s.reset_index().set_index("beginpoints")
ts = t['index']

df['point'] = df['Datetime'].map(ts).fillna(method="ffill")
```

The result:

```
              Datetime  Volume  Price  point
0  2013-04-15 21:45:00     100  50.00      0
1  2013-04-15 21:47:00      25  50.03      0
2  2013-04-15 21:52:00      15  50.05      0
3  2013-04-15 22:03:00       4  50.07      0
4  2013-04-15 22:04:00     145  50.38      1
5  2013-04-15 22:07:00      68  50.04      1
6  2013-04-15 22:12:00     157  49.93      1
7  2013-04-15 22:13:00      27  50.02      2
8  2013-04-15 22:19:00      37  49.91      2
```

Finally, just use `groupby` to calculate summary based on the `point`:

```
group= df.groupby(['point'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['Datetime'] = group[['Datetime']].first()
df2['Volume'] = group[['Volume']].sum() 
df2['Price'] = group[['Price']].first()
```

The result:

```
              Datetime  Volume  Price
0  2013-04-15 21:45:00     144  50.00
1  2013-04-15 22:04:00     370  50.38
2  2013-04-15 22:13:00      64  50.02
```

Comment: Thanks, clever solution combining `reset_index`, `set_index` and `map`. Works perfectly!